# Barycentric coordinates of the origin point of a quadrilateral

Tags: quadrilateral, barycentric-coordinates

I have a quadrilateral formed by the points A, B, C, D.

I want to get the barycentric coordinates u, v, w, x so that:

A*u + B*v + C*w + D*x = [0, 0]

How do I find the values of u, v, w, x knowing the coordinates A, B, C, D?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand. To find the barycentric coordinates u, v, w, x that satisfy the given linear constraint I suppose, you can solve the following system of equations:

Au + Bv + Cw + Dx = [0, 0]

u + v + w + x = 1     (since barycentric coordinates sum to 1)

Where A, B, C and D are the position vectors of points A, B, C and D respectively that form the quadrilateral.

Solving this system of equations will give you the barycentric coordinates u, v, w, x that satisfy the given constraint. Then you can solve the system of equations for a specific quadrilateral (by providing the position vectors of A, B, C and D).